# Is it possible to implement mixins in C#?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, mixins

I've heard that it's possible with extension methods, but I can't quite figure it out myself. I'd like to see a specific example if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 102):

It really depends on what you mean by "mixin" - everyone seems to have a slightly different idea. The kind of mixin I'd *like* to see (but which isn't available in C#) is making implementation-through-composition simple:

```
public class Mixin : ISomeInterface
{
    private SomeImplementation impl implements ISomeInterface;

    public void OneMethod()
    {
        // Specialise just this method
    }
}
```

The compiler would implement ISomeInterface just by proxying every member to "impl" unless there was another implementation in the class directly.

None of this is possible at the moment though :)

Comment: Anders please add this to C# 5!!

Comment: I find it annoying that C++ experts make statements like "Prefer composition to inheritance" yet the language (C++ or C#) offers precious little help to do the "right thing".

Comment: I'd love that, implementing complex interfaces (i.e. more than 2 or 3 members) by composition is a pain...

Comment: Just saw a [connect open on this on the VS Feedback rss feed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/627979/).  Go and vote if you likes.

Comment: The Oxygene language has that. But [I don't think](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/11/interface-implementation-through_09.html) that's a good solution for the problem. We need a higher level concept, like traits, or [roles](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/10/roles-in-c.html).

Comment: +1 This is something I'd really like to see also.  It could be especially handy if the generic system could do it with generic types (e.g. have a type which could wrap any interface type, passing through all of the interface members directly to the wrapped object, but could have its own members separate from those of the interface).  This could be helpful for making finalizers work in scenarios where some references should protect an object from finalization but others should not.

Comment: yet another delphi concept to be used in c# ... Anders for sure still does know the gotchas :)

Comment: I've started [implementing roles in C#](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2011/05/nroles-experiment-with-roles-in-c.html). Take a look. They can implement interfaces and bring these implementations to composing classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am not the downvoter, but since the question requests a specific example, I expect downvoter was nonplussed that the provided answer is a "Wouldn't it be nice?" rather than a presently-practical solution.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: If the OP had given a specific meaning for what he understood by the term "mix-in" it would have been easier to give a specific example of how it could be achieved. All we've got is "I've heard that it's possible" which doesn't really give much information. *I* don't really regard extension methods as mix-ins, but maybe the OP does. This is a classic case of the more effort the questioner puts into the question, the more they're likely to get out of the answers.

Comment: You can do something really close to this with [re-mix](http://remix.codeplex.com/). I've used it successfully in the past.

Answer (score 14):

I usually employ this pattern:

```
public interface IColor
{
    byte Red   {get;}
    byte Green {get;}
    byte Blue  {get;}
}

public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static byte Luminance(this IColor c)
    {
        return (byte)(c.Red*0.3 + c.Green*0.59+ c.Blue*0.11);
    }
}
```

I have the two definitions in the same source file/namespace.
That way the extensions are always available when the interface is used (with 'using').

This gives you a *limited mixin* as described in CMS' first link.

Limitations:

- no data fields
- no properties (you'll have to call myColor.Luminance() with parentheses, [extension properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/c-extension-properties) anyone?)

It's still sufficient for many situations.

It would be nice if they (MS) could add some compiler magic to auto-generate the extension class:

```
public interface IColor
{
    byte Red   {get;}
    byte Green {get;}
    byte Blue  {get;}

    // compiler generates anonymous extension class
    public static byte Luminance(this IColor c)     
    {
        return (byte)(c.Red*0.3 + c.Green*0.59+ c.Blue*0.11);
    }
}
```

Although Jon's proposed compiler trick would be even nicer.

Comment: I use the same . Extension methods on interfaces. I see this from wikpedia on mixins in c#.  "...Extension Methods provide additional functionality on an existing class without modifying the class. It then becomes possible to create a static helper class for specific functionality that defines the extension methods...."

Comment: As risky as this is, this may be the only way to, without downloading any third party stuff, do what mixins are supposed to do -- keep things separate while allowing them to optionally be merged together at runtime. For reasons why this may be risky, for one, it's easy to accidentally override an existing method of the underlying object

Answer (score 10):

There is an open source framework that enables you to implement mixins via C#. Have a look on http://remix.codeplex.com/.

It is very easy to implement mixins with this framework. Just have a look on the samples and the "Additional Information" links given on the page.

Answer (score 4):

[LinFu](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/) and [Castle's DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/tree/master/src/Castle.Core.Tests/Mixins) implement mixins. COP (Composite Oriented Programming) could be considered as making a whole paradigm out of mixins. [This post from Anders Noras](http://web.archive.org/web/20081228224052/http://andersnoras.com/blogs/anoras/archive/2008/08/27/cop-c-4-0-and-doing-open-source-stuff.aspx) has useful informations and links.

EDIT: This is all possible with C# 2.0, without extension methods

Answer (score 4):

I needed something similar so I came up with the following using Reflection.Emit. In the following code a new type is dynamically generated which has a private member of type 'mixin'. All the calls to methods of 'mixin' interface are forwarded to this private member. A single parameter constructor is defined that takes an instance which implements the 'mixin' interface. Basically, it is equal to writing the following code for a given concrete type T and interface I:

```
class Z : T, I
{
    I impl;

    public Z(I impl)
    {
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    // Implement all methods of I by proxying them through this.impl
    // as follows: 
    //
    // I.Foo()
    // {
    //    return this.impl.Foo();
    // }
}
```

This is the class:

```
public class MixinGenerator
{
    public static Type CreateMixin(Type @base, Type mixin)
    {
        // Mixin must be an interface
        if (!mixin.IsInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException("mixin not an interface");

        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = DefineType(@base, new Type[]{mixin});

        FieldBuilder fb = typeBuilder.DefineField("impl", mixin, FieldAttributes.Private);

        DefineConstructor(typeBuilder, fb);

        DefineInterfaceMethods(typeBuilder, mixin, fb);

        Type t = typeBuilder.CreateType();

        return t;
    }

    static AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder;
    private static TypeBuilder DefineType(Type @base, Type [] interfaces)
    {
        assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        TypeBuilder b = moduleBuilder.DefineType(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            @base.Attributes,
            @base,
            interfaces);

        return b;
    }
    private static void DefineConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder)
    {
        ConstructorBuilder ctor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
            MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { fieldBuilder.FieldType });

        ILGenerator il = ctor.GetILGenerator();

        // Call base constructor
        ConstructorInfo baseCtorInfo =  typeBuilder.BaseType.GetConstructor(new Type[]{});
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeBuilder.BaseType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]));

        // Store type parameter in private field
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    private static void DefineInterfaceMethods(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Type mixin, FieldInfo instanceField)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = mixin.GetMethods();

        foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
        {
            MethodInfo fwdMethod = instanceField.FieldType.GetMethod(method.Name,
                method.GetParameters().Select((pi) => { return pi.ParameterType; }).ToArray<Type>());

            MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                                            fwdMethod.Name,
                                            // Could not call absract method, so remove flag
                                            fwdMethod.Attributes & (~MethodAttributes.Abstract),
                                            fwdMethod.ReturnType,
                                            fwdMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());

            methodBuilder.SetReturnType(method.ReturnType);
            typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, method);

            // Emit method body
            ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, instanceField);

            // Call with same parameters
            for (int i = 0; i < method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);
            }
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, fwdMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the usage:

```
public interface ISum
{
    int Sum(int x, int y);
}

public class SumImpl : ISum
{
    public int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public class Multiply
{        
    public int Mul(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}

// Generate a type that does multiply and sum
Type newType = MixinGenerator.CreateMixin(typeof(Multiply), typeof(ISum));

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(newType, new object[] { new SumImpl() });

int res = ((Multiply)instance).Mul(2, 4);
Console.WriteLine(res);
res = ((ISum)instance).Sum(1, 4);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use Reflection.Emit." Now they re-compile Problem to include Solution opcodes and have attained programming nirvana.

Answer (score 3):

You could also augment the extension method approach to incorporate state, in a pattern not unlike WPF's attached properties.

Here is an example with minimum boilerplate. Note that no modification are required on the target classes, including adding interfaces, unless you need to deal with the target class polymorphically - in which case you end up with something very close to actual Multiple Inheritance.

```
// Mixin class: mixin infrastructure and mixin component definitions
public static class Mixin
{ 
    // =====================================
    // ComponentFoo: Sample mixin component
    // =====================================

    //  ComponentFooState: ComponentFoo contents
    class ComponentFooState
    {
        public ComponentFooState() {
            // initialize as you like
            this.Name = "default name";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    // ComponentFoo methods

    // if you like, replace T with some interface 
    // implemented by your target class(es)

    public static void 
    SetName<T>(this T obj, string name) {
        var state = GetState(component_foo_states, obj);

        // do something with "obj" and "state"
        // for example: 

        state.Name = name + " the " + obj.GetType();


    }
    public static string
    GetName<T>(this T obj) {
        var state = GetState(component_foo_states, obj);

        return state.Name; 
    }

    // =====================================
    // boilerplate
    // =====================================

    //  instances of ComponentFoo's state container class,
    //  indexed by target object
    static readonly Dictionary<object, ComponentFooState>
    component_foo_states = new Dictionary<object, ComponentFooState>();

    // get a target class object's associated state
    // note lazy instantiation
    static TState
    GetState<TState>(Dictionary<object, TState> dict, object obj) 
    where TState : new() {
        TState ret;
        if(!dict.TryGet(obj, out ret))
            dict[obj] = ret = new TState();

        return ret;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
var some_obj = new SomeClass();
some_obj.SetName("Johny");
Console.WriteLine(some_obj.GetName()); // "Johny the SomeClass"
```

Note that it also works with null instances, since extension methods naturally do.

You might also consider using a WeakDictionary implementation to avoid memory leaks caused by the collection's holding on to target class references as keys.

Comment: The signature of GetState only has one Type Arg, but the calls to GetState by GetName and SetName pass in two. How is this really supposed to work?

Comment: @Thick_propheT, you're right of course. I made a few simplifications after the original post, but seem to have missed this bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a workaround [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/how-to-create-mixin-using-C-Sharp-4-0/), which while not entirely elegant, allows you to achieve fully observable mixin behavior. Additionally, IntelliSense still works!

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; //needed for ConditionalWeakTable
public interface MAgeProvider // use 'M' prefix to indicate mixin interface
{
    // nothing needed in here, it's just a 'marker' interface
}
public static class AgeProvider // implements the mixin using extensions methods
{
    static ConditionalWeakTable<MAgeProvider, Fields> table;
    static AgeProvider()
    {
        table = new ConditionalWeakTable<MAgeProvider, Fields>();
    }
    private sealed class Fields // mixin's fields held in private nested class
    {
        internal DateTime BirthDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    public static int GetAge(this MAgeProvider map)
    {
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime dtBorn = table.GetOrCreateValue(map).BirthDate;
        int age = ((dtNow.Year - dtBorn.Year) * 372
                   + (dtNow.Month - dtBorn.Month) * 31
                   + (dtNow.Day - dtBorn.Day)) / 372;
        return age;
    }
    public static void SetBirthDate(this MAgeProvider map, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        table.GetOrCreateValue(map).BirthDate = birthDate;
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    // contents unimportant
}
public class Human : Animal, MAgeProvider
{
    public string Name;
    public Human(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    // nothing needed in here to implement MAgeProvider
}
static class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Human h = new Human("Jim");
        h.SetBirthDate(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1));
        Console.WriteLine("Name {0}, Age = {1}", h.Name, h.GetAge());
        Human h2 = new Human("Fred");
        h2.SetBirthDate(new DateTime(1960, 6, 1));
        Console.WriteLine("Name {0}, Age = {1}", h2.Name, h2.GetAge());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base class that can store data you can enforce compiler safety and use marker interfaces.
That's more or less what "Mixins in C# 3.0" from the accepted answer proposes.

```
public static class ModelBaseMixins
{
    public interface IHasStuff{ }

    public static void AddStuff<TObjectBase>(this TObjectBase objectBase, Stuff stuff) where TObjectBase: ObjectBase, IHasStuff
    {
        var stuffStore = objectBase.Get<IList<Stuff>>("stuffStore");
        stuffStore.Add(stuff);
    }
}
```

The ObjectBase:

```
public abstract class ObjectBase
{
    protected ModelBase()
    {
        _objects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _objects;

    internal void Add<T>(T thing, string name)
    {
        _objects[name] = thing;
    }

    internal T Get<T>(string name)
    {
        T thing = null;
        _objects.TryGetValue(name, out thing);

        return (T) thing;
    }
```

So if you have a Class you can inherit from 'ObjectBase' and decorate with IHasStuff you can add sutff now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mixin implementation I've just come up with. I'll probably use it with [a library of mine](https://github.com/Imms/Imms).

It's probably been done before, somewhere.

It's all statically typed, with no dictionaries or something. It requires a little bit of extra code per type, you don't need any storage per instance. On the other hand, it also gives you the flexibility of changing the mixin implementation on the fly, if you so desire. No post-build, pre-build, mid-build tools.

It has some limitations, but it does allow things like overriding and so on.

We begin by defining a marker interface. Perhaps something will be added to it later:

```
public interface Mixin {}
```

This interface is implemented by mixins. Mixins are regular classes. Types do not inherit or implement mixins directly. They instead just expose an instance of the mixin using the interface:

```
public interface HasMixins {}

public interface Has<TMixin> : HasMixins
    where TMixin : Mixin {
    TMixin Mixin { get; }
}
```

Implementing this interface means supporting the mixin. It's important that it's implemented explicitly, since we're going to have several of these per type.

Now for a little trick using extension methods. We define:

```
public static class MixinUtils {
    public static TMixin Mixout<TMixin>(this Has<TMixin> what)
        where TMixin : Mixin {
        return what.Mixin;
    }
}
```

`Mixout` exposes the mixin of the appropriate type. Now, to test this out, let's define:

```
public abstract class Mixin1 : Mixin {}

public abstract class Mixin2 : Mixin {}

public abstract class Mixin3 : Mixin {}

public class Test : Has<Mixin1>, Has<Mixin2> {

    private class Mixin1Impl : Mixin1 {
        public static readonly Mixin1Impl Instance = new Mixin1Impl();
    }

    private class Mixin2Impl : Mixin2 {
        public static readonly Mixin2Impl Instance = new Mixin2Impl();
    }

    Mixin1 Has<Mixin1>.Mixin => Mixin1Impl.Instance;

    Mixin2 Has<Mixin2>.Mixin => Mixin2Impl.Instance;
}

static class TestThis {
    public static void run() {
        var t = new Test();
        var a = t.Mixout<Mixin1>();
        var b = t.Mixout<Mixin2>();
    }
}
```

Rather amusingly (though in retrospect, it does make sense), IntelliSense does not detect that the extension method `Mixout` applies to `Test`, but the compiler does accept it, as long as `Test` actually has the mixin. If you try,

```
t.Mixout<Mixin3>();
```

It gives you a compilation error.

You can go a bit fancy, and define the following method too:

```
[Obsolete("The object does not have this mixin.", true)]
public static TSome Mixout<TSome>(this HasMixins something) where TSome : Mixin {
    return default(TSome);
}
```

What this does is, a) display a method called `Mixout` in IntelliSense, reminding you of its existence, and b) provide a somewhat more descriptive error message (generated by the `Obsolete` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

There are, fundamentally, several techniques to getting Mixin behavior in your classes:

- Behavioral mixins that hold no state are easily done using extension methods
- Behavioral mixins for interfaces that use duck typing (currently, `IEnumerable` and `IDisposable`) [can use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8WbqTFlAeM) default interface members with explicit implementation of said interface. Then, then new interface behaves as a mixin where concrete behavior can be added and leveraged without using extension methods, and can support constructs such as `using` and `foreach`.
- Mixins that need state can be implemented very roughly by using extension methods and a static `ConditionalWeakTable` to hold data.
- Multiple inheritance mechanics can be crudely synthesized at compile-time (T4, source generators) or runtime (Reflection.Emit).

Answer (score 1):

Default implementation of interfaces have pretty much enabled mixins to be possible with a bit of creativity.

Here's a demo:

```
using System;

public class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var inst = new Baseline();
      Console.WriteLine("Baseline.Method() returns " + inst.Method());
      Console.WriteLine("Baseline.Method() returns " + inst.Method());
  }
}

public struct MixinImpl {
    public static MixinImpl Create() => new MixinImpl(); // Idiom to provide the mixin constructor
    private int counter;
    public int Method() => ++counter;
}

public interface Mixin {
    ref MixinImpl Impl { get; }
    int Method() => Impl.Method();
}

public class Baseline : Mixin {
    private MixinImpl mixinImpl = MixinImpl.Create();
    ref MixinImpl Mixin.Impl => ref mixinImpl;
}
```

So this works by defining a mixin as a `struct` and a corresponding `interface`; where the interface contains the mixin default implementation and the `struct` contains the state. This implementation has the benefit of *not breaking the ABI* when you add either state or methods to the mixin.

The only real downside is there's no way to do `protected` access qualifier. Your only protection choices are `public` and `private`. You can kind of fake protected by not providing the forwarder but it doesn't really work because half of the callers will be via variables of the interface type, which can see the Impl member and access members of the struct.

Here's the overhead in the user of the mixin isolated so you can see it alone:

```
: Mixin {
    private MixinImpl mixinImpl = MixinImpl.Create();
    ref MixinImpl Mixin.Impl => ref mixinImpl;
```

That's it. One interface declaration and two lines of code. The first line declares and creates the mixin state and the second line provides the glue that ties everything together. There's no limit to the number of mixins you can have either.

The overhead on the mixin provider is as follows:

```
    int Method() => Impl.Method();
```

Every `public` property and method that accesses anything `private` needs a forwarder from the `interface` to the `struct`.

Mixins done this way don't have inheritance; however you can fake it with composition and implementing the base interface in the derived `struct`. The `interface` forwarding provides capacity to do virtual methods while you're at it. This also means mixins can have mixins, but *what are you doing* if you need that.

Apologies; TIO's compiler is out of date and doesn't support default implementations.