# Refactoring: How can we abstract these classes

Tags: c#, abstract-class

There are some methods and member variables in some classes that look so much similar and I thought I can refactor and abstract them away... but I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing this:

so for example let's say I have these two classes:

```
public class CaseField
{
  private int mlObjectKey = CommonIndepClass.GetNextObjectKey();
  public int ObjectKey
  {
    get
    {
      return mlObjectKey;
    }
  }

  // some other specific methods...
}
```

and then another class:

```
public class AsOfField
{
   private int mlObjectKey = CommonIndepClass.GetNextObjectKey();

   public int ObjectKey
   {
       get
       {
          return mlObjectKey;
       }
   }

   // some specific methods ... 
}
```

So I was thinking if it is correct to create an Abstract class and factor those methods and member variables and put them in that abstract class:

```
public abstract class CommonFields
{
   private int mlObjectKey = CommonIndepClass.GetNextObjectKey();

   public int ObjectKey
   {
       get
       {
          return mlObjectKey;
       }
   }

}

public class CaseField: CommonFields
{
  // just its own specific methods and member variables. 
}



public class AsOfField: CommonFields
{
  // just its own specific methods and member variables. 
}
```

Comment: As a mechanism to keep your code DRY, this looks perfect and will continue to offer benefits as you continue to develop more CommonField types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems not unreasonable.

An alternative is to implement this functionality using [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). That would allow you to define one class with common functionality, but you wouldn't have to implement a common base class. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255553/is-it-possible-to-implement-mixins-in-c) for more details.

Comment: hmm..thanks, I hadn't even heard about that word "mixins"... will study it..but if it got too much of learning curve, so the abstraction I had here is also correct? I was worried about those member variables, etc...

Comment: They're called "Extension Methods" in .NET land, I believe