# Can Interfaces be a substitute for Multiple Inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#

Can Interfaces be a substitute for Multiple Inheritance in C#?

EDIT: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579090/why-c-doesnt-support-multiple-inheritence-can-interfaces-be-used-as-a-substi

Which was a duplicate of: [Should C# have multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple inheritance implies that you inherit functionality from multiple base classes. Since interfaces define interfaces, not implementations, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, yes. The classic "is-a" relationship that inheritance provides can be expanded with the use of interfaces. Meaning, if a class inherits from another class, and implements 3 interfaces, an object of this class can be passed into a method that takes the base class, or any of the three interfaces as parameters. So, in a sense, this class "is-a" one of 4 different things. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, interfaces can allow you to have multiple is-a relationships with other categories of classes. This is part of why multiple inheritance is used.

For example,

```
public class TradeReport : IReport, ITrade, IComplianceRecord
```

Provided the class above implements the methods of all three interfaces meaningfully, you can use it to describe a report, a trade, and a compliance record.

But, that's the limit. There's no implementation inheritance in interfaces.