# Multiple Inheritance using XmlAttribute element?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class and inheritance like this in my deserializable class file as shown below.  I want to create another class called `VendorBase` which has
Xml attribute called `Vendor`. I want my `Customer` class to inherit that as well. How can i achieve it?

```
public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Customer")]
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "FieldValue")]
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }

}

public class VendorBase
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [C# does not support multiple inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456154/does-c-sharp-support-multiple-inheritance).

Comment: You can't without injecting `Vendor` in the inheritance chain.  Why not just add the property to `Customer`?

Comment: Thank You Stanley. I could do that but I want my code little neater fso that the future programmers wont get confused.. I was playing with interfaces but not able to get the right way to do it.