# Simulating multiple inheritance with TableEntity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I read that multiple inheritance doesn't exist in c# but [can be mocked by using interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456154/does-c-sharp-support-multiple-inheritance)

I am trying to do something similar and it doesn't seem to be working. Wondering what I might be doing wrong. I've defined my concrete class to inherit from:

```cs
public class AppSettings {
    public string CosmosDbPrimaryKey {get; set;}
}
```

and then my "super" class that inherits from `AppSettings` directly and implements `ITableEntity`. This class should ultimately act as if it inherited from both AppSettings and TableEntity.

```cs
public class AppSettingsRow: AppSettings, ITableEntity
    {
        private readonly TableEntity _tableEntity;
        public AppSettingsRow()
        {
            _tableEntity = new TableEntity();
        }

        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string ETag { get; set; }

        public void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            _tableEntity.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);
        }

        public IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            return _tableEntity.WriteEntity(operationContext);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I actually use the class and list rows from a table the AppSettings field show up as null.

If I do the *opposite* and inherit directly from TableEntity and implement AppSettings it works just fine however this is not desirable for me. AppSettings is likely to change with time and I don't want to have to maintain the two separate models every time a change happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And why multiple inheritance? To me, it seems that you are trying to have a class with 2 purposes which is contrary to the **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)**.

Comment: _I don't want to have to maintain the two separate models_ But you still want two have two independent classses??

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `TableEntity` uses reflection to enumerate the serializable properties of the concrete type. You don't need to inherit from `TableEntity` at all in this case, just implement your own serialization. Consider calling `TableEntity.ReadUserObject(this, properties, operationContext)` in your `ReadEntity` method.