# Regarding multiple inheritance

Tags: multiple-inheritance

Can anyone explain me

why c# not supporting multiple inheritance since c++ supporting multiple inheritance ? how it is possible ? How c++ supports ?

Comment: Because multiple inheritance is dirty : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#Criticisms

Comment: Can you explain what feature of multiple inheritance you are looking for in C#, and maybe we can recommend something else that will achieve your goals?

Comment: Ten questions, zero accepted? When you get a best answer to a question, it would be courteous to select that as your accepted answer. It's a nice way of saying "thank you" to the people who take time to read and reply to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a small correction: C# does support multiple *interface* inheritance. It doesn't support multiple *implementation* inheritance.

The two big reasons MI isn't supported are:

- Chances are good that you can do what you want with multiple interface inheritance anyway.
- It adds a lot of complexity to the compiler implementation.

IMO, in many cases, the availability of multiple inheritance in a language causes that feature to be frequently abused. Single inheritance already gets wedged into a lot of class hierarchies unnecessarily when something like composition would do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

From an MSDN blog on C# frequently asked questions you can find [this answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85562.aspx).  There is also this [highly rated Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance).