# Why C# doen't support multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should C# include multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)

One of my friend asked me the question
i.e.Why C# doen't support multiple inheritance

Comment: Lots of questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance

Comment: But why does it should support them? The net value of having multiple inheritance is quite low in comparison with increase of language's complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using interfaces is more flexible and eliminates the ambiguity of multiple inheritance.

Further details, [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85562.aspx).

Comment: Since interfaces are a subset of multiple inheritance, I'm not sure how you conclude that they are more flexible.

Comment: how can it be more flexible? inheriting from a class is nothing like inheriting from a interface, the interface only defines a contract without actual functionality/code-reuse

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance complicates the language and its implementation. I suspect the designers decided that the gains weren't worth the pains.

Answer (score 1):

C#, like Java supports a way to deal with multiple inheritance by allowing a class to implement multiple Interfaces. Its not quite multiple inheritance but it can accomplish what you want to get done.

Comment: Interestingly, there is a version of Eiffel for .Net that uses CLR interfaces and delegates to implement Eiffel's version if Multiple Inheritance.