# Why C# does not support multiple inheritance?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should C# include multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)
>   [Why C# doen’t support multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865302/why-c-doent-support-multiple-inheritance)

Why C# does not support multiple inheritance where as C++ supports it and we have to achieve the same using Interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't need to provide reasons for features to *not* be included. Rather, features must be justified on a cost-benefit basis. C# doesn't have multiple inheritance because the benefit of the feature does not justify the costs.  Why *should* C# have multiple inheritance? It gets by without it perfectly well.

Comment: Actually this is a question asked in Accenture interview and some problem called Diamond problem was mentioned.

Comment: @Arup: if your question is actually "what are some of the interesting design problems involving multiple inheritance in C++?" then that's the question you should have asked. The answer to all questions of the form "why doesn't C# have feature X?" is either "no one thought of it", or "we thought of it but couldn't justify the cost given our budget".

Comment: Ok Eric got your point. I will try to put it that way next time.

Comment: @Arup Chaudhury, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem