# Why Interface support multiple inheritance and class doesnt in c#

Tags: c#, class, interface, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why C# doen't support multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865302/why-c-doent-support-multiple-inheritance)
>   [Should C# include multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)

i like to what is reason for interface support multiple inheritance and class doesnt support

Comment: Same as [Why C# doen't support multiple inheritance ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865302/why-c-doent-support-multiple-inheritance).

Comment: which is a dup of [Should C# include multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: @Marc, it was closed as such, but I don't really agree.  Why it was designed that way and whether it was the right design are different issues.

Comment: @Matthew - I thought the same thing about this one, which is why I didn't close it ;p (I didn't close the other one, either)

Comment: I agree with Matthew, this is not a dup, as the question is about why it was supported for interfaces but not classes.  I don't see an answer to that in either question and I think it's interesting.

Comment: @Kirk, actually I closed this as a dup of the link I posted.  I don't think *that* is a dup of Marc's link (even though it was closed as one).  Pretty subjective. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be very interested in a more authoritative answer, but here's my take.

In languages that support multiple inheritance, the key ambiguity that is (arguably) unsatisfactorily resolved is what happens when you subclass from two types that both define a method with the same signature.  For example:

```
public class BaseClass1 
{
    public string SomeMethod() 
    {
        return "Implementation1";
    }
}

public class BaseClass2 
{
    public string SomeMethod() 
    {
        return "Implementation2";
    }
}

public class MySuclass : BaseClass1, BaseClass2 
{
}
```

Now what does the following return?

```
MySubclass mySubclass = new MySubclass();
string s = mySubclass.SomeMethod();
```

In C#, explicit interface implementation allows you to easily resolve this by definining *both*.  After converting `BaseClass1` and `BaseClass2` to interfaces, we can have

```
public class MySuclass : IBaseClass1, IBaseClass2 
{
    string IBaseClass1.SomeMethod()
    {
        return "Implementation1";
    }

    string IBaseClass2.SomeMethod()
    {
        return "Implementation2";
    }
}
```

The key of course being that there is no ambiguity with this syntax as it's not possible to access `SomeMethod` without first casting the target to either `IBaseClass1` or `IBaseClass2`.

Answer (score 8):

I would rather 'negate' your statement.. "interface support multiple inheritance".

Interface is NOT actually inheritance, it is JUST a "contract" of service/behavior that a class abides with.

By implementing an interface a class does NOT inherit anything per se.

And since a class/entity can bind with multiple contracts (behaviours), we can implement multiple interfaces in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Because these are conceptually two totally different things.

If you inherit from a class, you inherit the code of the base class.
If you implement (not inherit!) an interface, you force your implementing class to have some predefined method/event/property signatures.

While multiple inheritance for classes is a notorious source of errors and confusion, having many interfaces in a class' inheritance list is about combining various behavioural aspects, and as such it is an important instrument for component-based programming.

Or, in other words: It is an implementation of the *Favour Composition over Inheritance* design principle.

Thomas