# Does C# support multiple inheritance 4.0?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I recently took a [practice C# skills](http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=c-skills-test) test and one of the questions was,

> Does C# support multiple inheritance?

I answered yes, and was was marked wrong. After some research online, its full of answers of why it is not supported:

[Multiple inheritance support in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028486/multiple-inheritance-support-in-c-sharp)

[Why is Multiple Inheritance not allowed in Java or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/652495/Why-does-csharp-doesnt-support-Multiple-inheritanc

Then I went and tried to replicate the error I should be getting when trying to inherit from a Class that already inherited from a Base Class, and there is no error. I am using console application, and I recently upgraded to .net 4.5, maybe things have changed?

**Code for how I tested:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Leo bk = new Leo();

            bk.avgWords();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public void bubbleSort(int[] input)
        {

        }

        public void insertionSort(int[] input)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Gatsby : Books
    {


        public override void avgWords()
        {

            Console.WriteLine(5);

        }

    }

    public class Leo : Gatsby
    {


        public override void avgWords()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(7);
        }

    }

    public class Dicaprio : Leo
    {


    }

    public class Books
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }

        public virtual void avgWords()
        {


            Console.WriteLine(3);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what multiple inheritance means.

Comment: This is Multi-level inheritance, not Multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably meant can a class derive from two or more base classes, which it cannot.  Confusing wording.

```
public abstract class A1;
public abstract class A2;
public abstract class B : A2;
public class C : A1, A2; // invalid
public class D : B; // valid
```

Comment: Not to nit pick too much, but "multiple inheritance" is a technical term, so the wording is not confusing, the asker simply isn't familiar with the term.

Comment: You are correct, but for most the question is more about knowing what the term "multiple inheritance" means and not the practice itself.  If a simple pseudo code example was given, this person would not have incorrectly answered the question.

Answer (score 10):

> Then I went and tried to replicate the error I should be getting when trying to inherit from a Class that already inherited from a Base Class, and there is no error. I am using console application, and I recently upgraded to .net 4.5, maybe things have changed?

No, that is still considered single inheritance.  Your class only inherits from a single base class.

Some languages, like C++, allow you to inherit from more than one class.  The C# version would be something like:

```
class Foo {} 
class Bar {}

// This is invalid in C#!
class Baz : Foo, Bar {}
```

However, that's not allowed.

Note that C# *does* allow you to implement multiple interfaces, however.

Answer (score 5):

> Does C# support multiple inheritance?

You cannot inherit from multiple base classes, but as with COM, you can re-use multiple base classes through multiple interfaces and [containment and delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
// class C1 implements interface I1
interface I1
{
    void M1();
}

class C1 : I1
{
    public void M1() { Console.WriteLine("C1.M1"); }
}

// class C2 implements interface I2
interface I2
{
    void M2();
}

class C2 : I2
{
    public void M2() { Console.WriteLine("C2.M2"); }
}

// class C reuses C1 and C2
// it implements I1 and I2 and delegates them accordingly
class C: I1, I2
{
    C1 c1;
    C2 c2;

    void I1.M1() { c1.M1(); }

    void I2.M2() { c2.M2(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) allows a class to inherit from more than one parent class. C# doesn't allow multiple inheritace; that does not mean a class' characteristics can be inherited only *once*.

It is possible to use multiple "implementation" through interfaces:

```
interface IInterface
{
    ...
}

interface IAnotherInterface
{
    ...
}

class MyClass : IInterface, IAnotherInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not considered as multiple inheretence but it is a multi-level or chain inheretence.

Multiple inheretence is when for example you have 3 classes A,B,and C.
And class C is inheriting from classes A and B at the same time.

The problem with multiple inheretence and why it is not supported is that because if you have a method with the same name in both classes A and B with different implementation, and you want to use that method in class C, then class C will be confused of which of those method should it use. To prevent the confusion and ambiguity multiple inheretence is not supported in C#.