# Why can't you do multiple inheritance in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should C# include multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)

Why doesn't c# support multiple inheritance?

```
public partial class Child: Parent1 
{
  void MakeParent1Mad();
}

public partial class Child: Parent2
{
  void MakeParent2Mad();
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 5):

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dachou/net-and-multiple-inheritance)

> - .NET was designed to support
>   multiple languages, but not all
>   languages can effectively support
>   multiple inheritance. Or technically
>   they could, but the complexities added
>   in language semantics would make some
>   of those languages more difficult to
>   use (and less similar to their roots,
>   like VB, and for backward
>   compatibility reasons) and not worth
>   the trade-off of being able to reuse
>   code in the manner of multiple
>   inheritance
> - It would also make
>   cross-language library
>   interoperability (via CLS compliance)
>   less of a reality than it is today,
>   which is one of the most compelling
>   features of .NET. There are over 50
>   languages supported on .NET in over 70
>   implementations today
> - The most
>   visible factor is language semantics
>   complexity. In C++ we needed to add
>   explicit language features in order to
>   address ambiguities (such as the
>   classic diamond problem) caused by
>   multiple inheritance, such as the
>   "virtual" keyword to support virtual
>   inheritance to help the compiler
>   resolve inheritance paths (and we had
>   to use it correctly too)
> - As we know
>   code is written 20% of the time, but
>   read 80% of the time. Thus advocates
>   on simplicity side prefer not to add
>   language features for the sake of
>   keeping semantics simple. In
>   comparison C# code is significantly
>   simpler to read than C++ code, and
>   arguably easier to write