# Is interface can achieve multiple inheritance in c#.net?Explain with example if possible .

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

Its written in books that through interface we can achieve multiple interface is it true or not?

Because in interface we only define the method not logic but in inheritance we access the method with its logic inside it.Which is not possible in interface we have to write interface method logic in derive class which i dont want na do then .How i can achieve Multiple inhertiance in C#.net?

Comment: Please invest some time and correct the errors in your question.

Comment: You can have a class implement multiple interfaces - but that's **not multiple inheritance**. C# does **not** support multiple inheritance (like C++ does).

Comment: Lookup extension methods (which can be used on interfaces).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should C# include multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191691/should-c-include-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does using interfaces overcome the problem of multiple inheritance in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164582/how-does-using-interfaces-overcome-the-problem-of-multiple-inheritance-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

It's not multiple inheritance because you only 'inherit' the contract when you implement an interface. You do not inherit any behavior (what you probably mean if you say 'multiple inheritance').

A short example:

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>, IDisposable
{
    // Implement members from both interfaces.
    ...
}
```

The class `MyClass` behaves both as an `IComparable<MyClass>` and as an `IDisposable`.

Comment: +1, or you could use extension methods defined on the interfaces if method body is to be the same, instead of duplicating code in each class.

Comment: Multiple inheritance means - inheriting properties and  logic of two or more base class by derive class object.

Answer (score 0):

c# doesn't support multiple inheritance .

[Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c)

See the above link you will have clear understanding .