# How to extend EntityBase with several features?

Tags: c#

I have a base entity interface:

```
public interface IEntityBase
{
    Guid id { set; get; }
}
```

Now I want to have an entity, say SomeEntity, to have 2 features, Selectable and Movable.
Both Selectable and Movable are entities, so (logically) the should implement IEntityBase.
But then I can't define my SomeEntity like this:

```
class SomeEntity : ISelectable, IMovable {};
```

since I got the IEntityBase implemented twice :(

The bypass I found is not to implement IEntityBase in Selectable not Movable, and to create SomeEntity the following:

```
class SomeEntity : ISelectable, IMovable, IEntityBase {};
```

But my guts feel awkward...
Any other solutions?

Comment: *But then I can't define my SomeEntity like this* Actually you can.

Comment: If you have implemented IEntityBase in ISelectable and IMovable, then do you really need to implement it in SomeEntity which impliments one of these? In your case, if you remove IEntityBase from SomeEntity and then if you check someEntityInstance is IEntity, this will be true. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't show the definition of `ISelectable` and `IMovable` so it's not terribly clear but it seems like they are inheriting/extending `IEntity`. If so then the question is why? Does something really need to be an `IEntity` in order to define the members in either of the other two interfaces? I would steer away from interface inheritance if the answer is no (you are creating unnecessary coupling between the interface types and defeating the purpose of interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I was sure I cannot.
@blins, 
    `code`public interface IMovableEntity : IEntityBase {
        void Move();
    };
    
    public interface ISelectableEntity : IEntityBase {
        void Select();
    };`code`
But that's not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> But then I can't define my SomeEntity like this:
>
> `class SomeEntity : ISelectable, IMovable {};`
>
> since I got the IEntityBase implemented twice :(

Yes, you can! That's the great thing about interfaces: They [allow diamond inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5164582/87698).

Here's a fiddle to prove that this compiles just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qChku9

Answer (score 0):

You can define `class SomeEntity : ISelectable, IMovable {};` even if `IMovable` implements `ISelectable`. Interfaces have only declarations, so there couldn't be ambiguous situation when it's not clear what method should be implemented. But you could implement methods explicitly.